# Рекурсивное динамическое меню Angular

Tags: javascript, меню, angular

Имеется API, который по запросу отправляет структуру главного меню.

```
(9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "582", language_id: "1", index: "1", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
1: {id: "585", language_id: "1", index: "4", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
2: {id: "588", language_id: "1", index: "7", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
3: {id: "591", language_id: "1", index: "10", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
4: {id: "594", language_id: "1", index: "13", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
5: {id: "600", language_id: "1", index: "19", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
6: {id: "620", language_id: "1", index: "22", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
7: {id: "627", language_id: "1", index: "24", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
8: {id: "630", language_id: "1", index: "25", root: "1", watch: "1", …}
```

При отправке id родителя, сервер присылает его потомка (подменю). 
Вопрос таков, как одновременно - получить родителей, отправить айди, получить потомков и все это дело вывести как нормальное меню с дропдаунами?

Comment: а api публичное  могу доступ получяить или она утебя локальное

Comment: ну если вы знаете айди родителей - в чем проблема сделать запросы и получить потомков?

Comment: @overthesanity в этом и загвоздка. не понимаю как сразу отправить 9 запросов с 9 разными айди, а потом собрать все эти 9 ответов. отправка идет по методу get

Comment: ну массив промисов выполнить https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @Санитариум angular не работает с промисами, а с потоками

Comment: и  в чем проблема. промисы или потоки. не вижу проблемы

Comment: в том что `Promise.all` к этому не имеет отношения

Comment: Всем спасибо. Решилось с применением forkJoin (rxjs)